# JavaFX modal dialog fxml not loading. Load Exception

Tags: javafx

I've recently discovered JavaFX and have create a working application with a single main window. However, when I try to load a second `fxml` file to later be used as a modal window, I get errors. Here is my code, and the error produced.

```
public class Main extends Application {
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("main.fxml"));
    Parent modal = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("details.fxml"));

    primaryStage.setTitle("My app");
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 600, 400));
    primaryStage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}
```

This works without the second `FXMLLoader`, i.e. the `modal` one. But with this line included I get the following error:

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$1(LauncherImpl.java:182)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/home/..[mydirectory]../details.fxml:18
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2601)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.access$700(FXMLLoader.java:103)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:922)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:971)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:220)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:744)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2707)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2527)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3214)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
at sample.Main.start(Main.java:38)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$8(LauncherImpl.java:863)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$7(PlatformImpl.java:326)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$5(PlatformImpl.java:295)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$6(PlatformImpl.java:294)
at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$null$5(GtkApplication.java:139)
... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sample.Details
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:920)
... 22 more
Exception running application sample.Main

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Any ideas what might be the problem? Once working, I would try to open a modal dialog with details.fxml as the contents...

Comment: The stack trace seems to indicate that the controller class for `details.fxml`, which you have declared as `sample.Details` doesn't exist. So either the class name is wrong, the class is not in the `sample` package, or something is wrong with your deployment and the class is somehow not on the classpath (the last option is unlikely). Not really possible to answer without seeing your FXML and controller code.

Comment: @James_d I'm not entirely sure how to attach a Controller to the details.fxml. Can this be achieved in SceneBuilder? To create the new fxml file I just "add new fxml" file from the right clicking the project in IntelliJ. But it didn't create an associated Controller class file.

Comment: You *have*, as far as I can tell, specified a controller class. Can't you post the FXML file? What's on the line referenced in the stack trace?

Comment: @James_D it was the controller class name. Adding a new fxml file to the project in IntelliJ just created the xfml file, without a controller class, but IntelliJ automatically added a controller class name to the fxml file. I just added a Details controller and now it works. Thanks.

Comment: @Antinous Could you answer your question on how the problem was solved? Just for completeness.

Comment: @TM00 sure, although having had a downvote is somewhat discouraging.

Answer (score 0):

In InteliJ I added a new fxml file to the project by right clicking the project. Whilst this created a .fxml file which can be edited in SceneBuilder, it did not create an associated Controller class file.

If you open the .fxml file in text mode you will find at the top a reference to a controller class. You need to create this in your project manually for everything to work. I did this by copying the original controller file, renaming it, and deleting any irrelevant content.